# How to include the unique id of each instance for sake of mapping in the future

Tags: java, weka

I am using weka java API to classify couple of my instances, the file that I feed my weka file with is as follow:

```
0.3,0.1,1
0.0,0.04,0
0.0,0.03,1
```

And all of the above instances have unique id assigned to them for example the first row has id of 1098...
I wrote the following code which use weka java API to classify the result and return those instances that are classified incorrectly:

```
public static void SVM(ArrayList<String[]> testData) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
        Exception {
```

BufferedReader breader = null;
        breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("weka/train.txt"));

```
    Instances train = new Instances(breader);
    train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

    Instances unlabeled = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "weka/test.txt")));

    breader.close();
    // set class attribute
    unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);
    // create copy
    Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);
     LibSVM svm = new LibSVM();
     svm.buildClassifier(train);
     Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);

     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "weka/labeledSVM.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) {
            double clsLabel = svm.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
            if(unlabeled.instance(i).value(5)!=clsLabel){
                writer.write("the unique id is: "+testData.get(i)[0] + " real label of the text is :  "+ unlabeled.instance(i).toString() + ", According to Algorithm reult label is: " + clsLabel);
writer.newLine();
        }
           writer.flush();
           writer.close();

            }
```

But a big problem is that the mapping between the unique id and the instance labeled by algorithm is incorrect, so I am wondering if there is any way that I can include the unique id of each text inside the instances that I have but tell the weka classifier to ignore it ?

for example something like this:

```
1980,0.3,0.1,1
1981,0.0,0.04,0
1982,0.0,0.03,0
```

or any other suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this was to create my own subclass of Instance.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Use "AddID" filter which will assign a uniqueID to every instance, then use FilteredClassifier i.e. weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.